# Amendable console output in Python

Tags: command-line, python, console, ipython

Some programs are able to amend console output, wget easily comes to mind.

[image]

How can I do that in pure Python? I know IPython has [clear_output()](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-0.13/api/generated/IPython.core.display.html#IPython.core.display.clear_output). I tried that but even that does not work. And I would prefer pure Python.

```
from IPython.core.display import clear_output
from time import sleep

for i in range(100):
    clear_output()
    print '[', '='*i, ' '*(100-i), ']'
    sleep(0.1)
```

[image: asciicast]

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are actually a number of packages that allow you to write a command line interface. I know that [click has a progress bar](http://click.pocoo.org/4/utils/#showing-progress-bars), for instance.

Oh, and regarding your requirement "pure python", that my friend is something that is unpythonic. Python wants you to use third party packages.

[image: asciicast]

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. `Click` seems to be an amazing framework and I like it.

Answer (score 11):

Though a proper library is the best solution, I'd like to show a simple alternative: use `\r` (carriage return) instead of `\n` (line feed) for line endings, so that that the cursor is placed at the start of the current line, instead of on the next line.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from time import sleep

for i in range(100):
    print('[' + '='*i + ' '*(100-i) + ']', end='\r')
    sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: It does for me.

Comment: @Helio "A line by percent done" - what does that mean?

Comment: @ArekBulski What's your terminal width?

Comment: @muru: https://asciinema.org/a/18657

Comment: @Helio Yeah, that's caused by your terminal not being wide enough for 100+ characters.

Comment: @ArekBulski and that's why we should use libraries. They figure out your terminal width and scale, and detect the correct line endings and so on..

Comment: line ending characters are different for files, this use of `\r` and `\n` works on Windows and OSX just fine

Comment: @UncleZeiv Ah.. I was confused for a moment and didn't have a system on hand to check.

Answer (score 6):

Solution hinted by Helio works great! I needed to `pip install progressbar` first but then one of official examples works like a charm.

```
from progressbar import *    
pbar = ProgressBar(widgets=[Percentage(), Bar()], maxval=300).start()
for i in range(300):
    time.sleep(0.01)
    pbar.update(i+1)
pbar.finish()
```

Official site (with examples): https://code.google.com/p/python-progressbar/

Comment: I'm happy to help (I don't helped so much, but...).